# What is the mechanism behind class comments?

Tags: cron

```
 * @QueueWorker(
 *   id = "my_module_image_style",
 *   title = @Translation("Generate image styles"),
 *   cron = {"time" = 60}
 * )
```

And more specifically what is the effect of

```
 cron = {"time" = 60}
```

Comment: Don't agree with the close vote on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually called **annotations** which provide metadata about the class, and this **metadata** is gonna be extracted later on with our code to perform a specific logic.

in Drupal context since  The **QueueWorker** is just another drupal plugin, so it will be handled using the Plugin Manager which will extract this information from the **Annotations** and use them to build some logic for example in this case:

- **$id:** the unique identification of the QueueWorker plugin type instance.
- **$title:** some drupal method will extract the title from the **Annotation** and use it to set The human-readable title of the plugin.
- **$cron:** another function or same function will extract the cron from the **annotation** and set us How much time Drupal cron should spend on calling.   this worker in seconds. Defaults to 15.

and every drupal plugin fllow this logic:

1. the **plugin manager** of this plugin is **Drupal\Core\Queue\QueueWorkerManager** wich will discover the implementations of the annotation class that has been set in `parent:construct()` arg 4 ,wich is : (**\Drupal\Core\Annotation\QueueWorker**) :

```php
  public function __construct(\Traversable $namespaces, CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend, ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler) {
    parent::__construct('Plugin/QueueWorker', $namespaces, $module_handler, 'Drupal\Core\Queue\QueueWorkerInterface', 'Drupal\Core\Annotation\QueueWorker');

  }
```

2. **@QueueWorker (Annotation class)**: this annotation is an implementation of the **\Drupal\Core\Annotation\QueueWorker** class
   where @QueueWorker = class name and the annotation attributes = the
   class properties.

   > actually in this class peoperty doc Comment you can find a description of each annotation attribute.

```php
   <?php namespace Drupal\Core\Annotation; 
    use Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin;  

  class QueueWorker extends Plugin {

  /**
   * The plugin ID.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  public $id;

  /**
   * The human-readable title of the plugin.
   *
   * @ingroup plugin_translatable
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation
   */
  public $title;

  /**
   * An associative array containing the optional key:
   *   - time: (optional) How much time Drupal cron should spend on calling
   *     this worker in seconds. Defaults to 15.
   *
   * @var array (optional)
   */
  public $cron;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The class comments are **Annotations** : 
What is Annotation mean ?

1. In general according to [techopedia.com](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5117/annotation-java)

   > Annotation is a term used in computer programming to refer to documentation and comments that may be found on code logic. Annotation is typically ignored once the code is executed or compiled.
2. In Drupal According to [Annotations](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/annotations-based-plugins) doc page:

   > Annotations for class discovery and metadata description.
   >   The Drupal plugin system has a set of reusable components that developers can use, override, and extend in their modules. Most of the plugins use annotations, which let classes register themselves as plugins and describe their metadata. (Annotations can also be used for other purposes, though at the moment, Drupal only uses them for the plugin system.)

A lot of frameworks use annotations too like symfony use it in many contexts like creating routes using annotations [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-annotations).

For the annotation example you put in your question is for **[QueueWorker](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Annotation%21QueueWorker.php/class/QueueWorker/8.9.x)** plugin:

```
cron = {"time" = 60}
```

the definition of cron property `QueueWorker::$cron` according to [QueueWorker::$cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Annotation%21QueueWorker.php/property/QueueWorker%3A%3Acron/8.9.x) it mean:

> **time:** (optional) How much time Drupal cron should spend on calling this worker in seconds. Defaults to 15.

Answer (score 4):

Those are called annotations, and in this context, they are used for [plugin discovery](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/annotations-based-plugins).

This:

```
cron = {"time" = 60}
```

Signifies a property of the `QueueWorker` annotation; specifically [QueueWorker::$cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Annotation%21QueueWorker.php/property/QueueWorker%3A%3Acron/8.8.x), which is:

> How much time Drupal cron should spend on calling this worker in seconds. Defaults to 15.